# Finding elements in a group (beginner question)

Tags: group-theory

I am really stuck on a very (it seems like) simple task in basic group theory task. I am a couple of days on it already, just don't know what to do... Here is the task details:

Let *G* be a group of 5 elements *G={x,y,z,t,u}* relative to binary operation * (we don't know if * is commutative or not). Assume that *z * t = y* and *x * y = z*. Also, I already proved that *u* is an identity (neutral) element. What I need to do is to calculate *x * t* and *t * x*. Based on operation table, I can clearly prove that *x * t = u* and *t * x = u* (i.e - *t* inverse to *x*, and vice versa because *G* is a group). The question is - can I calculate *x * t* (or *t * x*) without operation table, purely relaying on that *z * t = y* and *x * y = z*, and that *u* is an identity element in *G* relative to operation *? I tried to play with that, but it seems like that I need to prove, at least, that *x * y = y * x*, and then try to solve it. Any ideas?..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: " I can clearly prove that x * t = u and t * x = u (i.e - t inverse to x, and vice versa because G is a group). "  I don't see that at all. xyt = zt =y so xy = yt' so y'xy = t' but that's as far as I can see..

Comment: If you are able to, you can use the fact that since $G$ has five elements it is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_5,+)$ and therefore commutative as there is only one group of size five up to isomorphism.  Alternatively if you are able to, you can use the fact that the smallest nonabelian group is of size six which is $S_3$.  @bungo proving that $u$ is the identity is pretty immediate since one of the five must be the identity for it to be a group and if it were any of the other four that would contradict the given equations.

Comment: Avoiding the table is equivalent to refusing to deduce $t*x = u$ by process of elimination.  Without process of elimination we have nothing that can not be deduced by limited information in larger groups.  So I don't think there is anything significant about our information yet. (we couldn't deduce it alone if there were more elements so we can't deduce it now unless we use that there are only 5 elements to eliminate.)

Comment: @fleablood its stated that there are exactly 5 elements. However, I don't think that elimination will work here. Oh, and about that I can see that x * t = u - I didn't solved it yet purely using equations, I have built an operation table and can clearly see each m * n operation result (and there is only one solution per each m * n = k in a Group, as we know).

Comment: @JMoravitz I can only use basic Group properties to solve that one: Closure, Associativity, Identity element, Inverse element, Uniqueness of identity element and inverses, and also if a * b = c * b then a=c together with if b * c = b * a, again - a = c.

Answer (score 1):

[I will omit the symbol $*$, and write (for instance) $xy$ for $x*y$.]

It is not possible to prove that $xt=u$ solely from knowing that $zt=y$, $xy=z$, and $u$ is the identity: you need to also use the fact that $G$ has only these $5$ elements.  For instance, suppose $G$ was the symmetric group $S_3$, with $x=(1\ 2)$, $t=(1\ 3)$, $y=(2\ 3)$, $z=(1\ 3\ 2)$.  Then $zt=y$ and $xy=z$, but $xt=(1\ 2\ 3)$ is not the identity.

(From a more sophisticated perspective, here's how you can come up with such an example.  The equations $xy=z$ and $zt=y$ say that $xyt=y$, or $x=yt^{-1}y^{-1}$.  So $x$ and $t^{-1}$ are conjugate.  To find an example of this, you just have to choose conjugate elements $x$ and $s$ of a group which are not equal, set $t=s^{-1}$, let $y$ be something that conjugates $s$ to $x$, and let $z=xy$.)

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I cannot use conjugation, since its not defined yet in that level. I can only use the following Group properties: Closure, Associativity, Identity element, Inverse element, Uniqueness of identity element and inverses, and also if a * b = c * b then a=c together with if b * c = b * a, again - a = c. Also, the above group has exactly 5 different elements and it doesn't said that its commutative.